# How did Harry know how Voldemort had lost his powers?

Tags: harry-potter, powers

At the end of *The Chamber of Secrets* Harry says:

> “No one knows why you lost your powers when you attacked me,” said Harry abruptly. “I don’t know myself. But I know why you couldn’t kill me. Because my mother died to save me.”

If no one knew how Voldemort lost his powers as it can be written in the first chapter of the third book this:

> Harry had escaped from the same attack with nothing more than a scar on his forehead, when Voldemort's curse, instead of killing him, had rebounded upon its originator.

Comment: Didn't Voldemort himself tell him that at the climax of *The Philosopher's Stone*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Didn't People Think That Voldemort Died After His Attack on Baby Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/why-didnt-people-think-that-voldemort-died-after-his-attack-on-baby-harry)

Comment: @DanielRoseman But hasn't he lost his powers because the curse has rebounded?

Answer (score 2):

Due to Lily's sacrifice of love, Voldemort's killing curse failed to affect Harry and instead rebounded on himself.

Had Voldemort died from the rebounding curse, there would be no mystery. The killing curse meant for baby Harry instead landed on the perpetrator and ended him, as expected.

The mystery is why Voldemort *didn't* die. Why was he left alive, having simply lost his powers, *as opposed to* completely dead, which would have made sense?

[In 2004](http://www.accio-quote.org/themes/book6.htm) (before Book 6 was released and we were introduced to Horcruxes), J.K. Rowling hinted at this:

> We should be asking "Why didn't Voldemort die?" Not, "Why did Harry live?" but, "Why didn't Voldemort die?" The killing curse rebounded, so he should have died. Why didn't he? At the end of Goblet of Fire he says that one or more of the steps that he took enabled him to survive. You should be wondering what he did to make sure that he did not die — I will put it that way. I don't think that it is guessable. It may be — someone could guess it — but you should be asking yourself that question, particularly now that you know about the prophesy.

Comment: But by the same token, Voldemort should have died numerous time before that - during the duel at the end of the *The Goblet of Fire*, an ambush (The Battle of the Seven Potters) in *The Deathly Hallows*, during the final battle when Harry Potter offered same protection to everyone defending Hogwarts... I think there is something more about it.

Comment: There is a narrative difference between the end of the second and the beginning of the third book regarding Voldermort loss of powers.

Harry states at the end of the second book that no one knows why Voldemort lost his powers that night…  while 
At the beginning of the third book it is stated that due to the curse he had lost his powers.

Answer (score 0):

But if everyone knows that the curse has rebounded on Voldemort (causing his destruction and loss of powers) because Harry says:

> No one knows why you lost your powers when you attacked me,

Even at the beginning of the second book it is written that no one knows the reason for the loss of Voldemort's powers:

> “Harry’s parents had died in Voldemort’s attack, but Harry had escaped with his lightning scar, and somehow — nobody understood why — Voldemort’s powers had been destroyed the instant he had failed to kill Harry.”

only in the third is information about the rebound of the curse revealed to us:

> Harry had escaped from the same attack with nothing more than a scar on his forehead, when Voldemort's curse, instead of killing him, had rebounded upon its originator.

For me this is a writing mistake. Because in the first two books no one knows how Voldemort loses his powers (Harry often says this) and suddenly in the third we are told that the curse has rebounded.

Comment: Nobody knew *at the **beginning** of the second book*, but by the *end* of the second book, Harry clearly *has* figured it out, as your quote in the question demonstrates. The third book then reflects this. Forgive me, but I'm not seeing the plot hole here.

Comment: @F1Krazy at the end of the second book Harry only knows that he was protected by his mom's sacrifice. But he doesn't know why Voldemort lost his powers: "No one knows why you lost your powers when you attacked me." only at the beginning of the third book is it known that the curse has rebounded. But in the first two preceding books this information had been omitted otherwise Harry would never have said that no one knew how Voldemort had lost his powers.